# Mysql Query Issue - Date GroupBy

Tags: mysql

I'm having a huge issue with the sql query below , basically i want to group the table by date "Y-m-d" , find the minimum value for that group and return the time it occurred .

However it keeps returning time = 00:00:00 and i have no idea what is wrong . Any help would be highly appreciated .

**e.g : for the first result , it correctly calculated the minimum price for that group but the time was 04:00:00 , but it still returned 00:00:00**

*Based on the id returned , it seems its returning the date for the first element of that group - not the actual date of the minimum price occurring.*

```
Select val_date 
     , id
     , MIN(average_price) AS min_value 
  from tableY
 GROUP 
    BY Month(val_date) 
     , Year(val_date) 
     , Day(val_date);
```

Table :

[image: sql]

Result :

```
[{"val_date":"2017-01-01 00:00:00","id":1,"min_value":964.33},
{"val_date":"2017-01-02 00:00:00","id":25,"min_value":998.24},
{"val_date":"2017-01-03 00:00:00","id":49,"min_value":1016.4},
{"val_date":"2017-01-04 00:00:00","id":73,"min_value":1034.02}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with **JAVA**?

Comment: your vat_date not contain time  .. are you sure is a valida  datetime colum ... and not simply a date column?  .. eventually update your question adding the  table schema

Comment: @scaisEdge - i check phpmyadmin and it is in datetime format '2  val_date Index  datetime  '

Comment: then could be that when you store tha values  you store only the date and not the time ..  check for you insert code ..

Comment: See the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html particularly "If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled...indeterminate"

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question like that. If you have an update then by all means update but don't remove everything leaving a placeholder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select val_date 
     , id
     , MIN(average_price) AS min_value 
  from tableY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%m') 
     , DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%Y') 
     , DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%d';
```

**OR**

```
Select val_date 
     , id
     , MIN(average_price) AS min_value 
  from tableY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its still returning 00:00:00